# If Sklivvz was elected moderator in an election, why doesn't he hold the Sheriff badge?

Tags: bug, badges

I just noticed that the [Sheriff badge holders](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/94/sheriff) does not include [Sklivvz](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/96/sklivvz). This badge is described as:

> Served as an elected moderator for at least 1 year.

From what I see, he was elected in the [2012 Moderator Election](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election). So he fulfilled the requirements over 4 years ago.

I am aware that he is a [former SE employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291305/209901) so there might be some collision with the SE-employee super powers he probably had by May 11 '13 when the other elected members got this bage.

Comment: Weird.  Occasionally I see people link little scriptlets that show SE's actual code for calculating stuff like who gets a badge.  Does anyone know how to look that up here?  Looking at the code might reveal the bug.

Comment: I think there should be a badge for noticing stuff like this.

Answer (score 3):

I should have both Constable and Sheriff (as I was a pro-tem and then an elected mod). The problem is that for some reason which I don't remember we put up a black list to prevent this badge from being awarded to devs.

OTOH it's weird because e.g. Marc Gravell doesn't have it on Stack Overflow where he was a mod, but animuson and bluefeet do. Hmmm.

Comment: well Marc Gravell is not listed in any of the list in [so](https://stackoverflow.com/election)

Comment: It is about the timing: [bluefeet got it on Feb 25 '15](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff) and joined the team somewhere in [June 2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/06/15/pivoting-into-a-new-career-please-welcome-taryn-pratt-bluefooted-community-manager/). Regarding animuson, he got it on Jul 5 '14 and joined the team somewhere in [April 2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/22/jnat-and-animuson-workin-on-ur-problemz/). Clearly, they waited for the badge to appply for the job :)

Comment: And then [Marc Gravell joined by June 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/09/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007/), long before [any election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) and I see no Constable badge has been awarded in SO.